# The cursor has data, but ListFragment only shows empty view

Tags: android, android-listfragment, simplecursoradapter

I was an iOS developer, and working on a Android project as a starter. Have been stuck in the following issue for one day. Please give me some help.

Might duplicated with [another stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14330002/listfragment-cursoradapter-showing-empty-no-data), but no one has answered that question.

My problem happened in the following code. The log.d actually shows the cursor has data, but the listfragment always shows empty view.
[image]

and here is the ImagesListAdapter

```
    public class ImagesListAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter { 
       private static final String TAG  = ImagesListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
       static final String[] from = new String[] {ImageData.C_LINK_URL };
       static final int[] to = new int[] { R.id.coupon_lbl};


// Constructor
public ImagesListAdapter(Context context, Cursor c) { 
    super(context, R.layout.image_cell, c, from, to, 0);
}
// This is where the actual binding of a cursor to view happens
@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
    super.bindView(row, context, cursor);
    // Manually bind created at timestamp to its view
    Log.d(TAG,"binding View.");

    String link = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ImageData.C_LINK_URL)); 
    TextView textCreatedAt = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.coupon_lbl); 
    textCreatedAt.setText(link); 
}
```

}

Where shall I start to debug this?

Comment: Post code of ImagesListAdapter.

Comment: Hi Giru Bhai, I have updated the question with some codes. Thanks for your prompt reply.

Comment: The `super.bindView` should be setting the text for you already. Why are you overriding it and trying to set it manually after the super call? Also, make sure `bindView` is getting called and make sure that your textview is returned when calling `row.findViewById` and that it's embedded in your image_cell layout.

Comment: @Chris,I am doing some simple testings, will do some logics here.

Comment: @CullenSUN See my edit. Also, make sure that there is data in the `link` field after you get the data from it.

Comment: my bindView is not called. Hence it is displaying the empty view

Comment: Does your layout for your fragment have a ListView with `android.R.id.list` as the ID? See beginning of [ListFragrament](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html) docs.

Comment: One last thing, try calling `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you set the adapter.

Comment: yes, I do have R.id.list, and tried adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). still not working. But thanks

Comment: Does your cursor contain the "_id" column?

Comment: @JimmyAu, Yes, I have it as BaseColumns._ID

Answer (score 0):

The codes look all fine, and one of my friends run the code from his IDE, and moved the setListAdapter() to "onCreateView", it works. However, I got nothing when I did the same. 
It is really weird...

I decided to use ListActivity at this moment, and everything works as expected.

Thanks all for your help and suggestions.